# Horse racing: Is there a trick, or will I get some upgrades later?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

Doing the Horse racing in the coliseum, I really wonder if there are some way to upgrade your horse, or if it gets better later in the game?

Really, I can't seem to win hard level races, and I'm 10 seconds off the reward time. And I don't feel I have bad races... I hit most of the stamina regen spots, and don't ram into the walls too much. Not perfect by any means, but I don't see how I really could cut 10 seconds off my time.

So is there some kind of trick/strategy, or a way to upgrade your horse, or do I just suck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're playing the Switch version you can purchase the golden reins for 10,000 gold from a merchant right next to registration. However, you can't use these to beat the Champion's Challenge times, as your time will not be recorded.

You do not need to beat the Champion's Challenge time to get a reward. All you need to do is beat the other racers. Make sure to keep boosting as much as you can (if you're able to, throughout the whole race) and make ample use of drifting.